# Delete an array element completely

Tags: perl

**Goal**: Remove a particular Value from an array

I have written a script and it works fine but I am not happy the way I have written it. So I am curious to know is there a better way to write it. please consider below use case:

I have a nested hash/hash/array...like below. I need to remove any array values which has `local` in their name:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my $hash = { esx1 => 
                    { cluster   => "clu1",
                      fd        => "fd1",
                      ds        => [ 
                                        'ds1',
                                        'ds2',
                                        'localds',
                                    ],  
                    },  
            esx2 => 
                    { cluster   => "clu2",
                      fd        => "fd2",
                      ds        => [ 
                                        'ds3',
                                        'ds4',
                                        'dslocal',
                                    ],  
                    },  
            };  


foreach my $a ( keys %$hash )
{
    foreach ( 0..$#{ $hash->{$a}->{ds} } ) 
    {   
        delete $hash->{$a}->{ds}->[$_] if $hash->{$a}->{ds}->[$_] =~ /local/i;
        @{ $hash->{$a}->{ds} } = grep defined, @{ $hash->{$a}->{ds} };
    }   
}

print Dumper ($hash);
```

so the script deletes the "`localds`" and "`dslocal`" and keeps everything else intact.

**Question**:

1. Is there a cleaner way to write the `foreach ( 0..$#{$hash->{$a}->{ds} } )` loop
2. If I do not write the `grep` line above, the resultant array has the value containing `local` deleted but is replaced by `undef`. Why is this happening.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why first iterate through array and delete elements and then look for "not-deleted" nodes (side note - this `grep` should be outside loop)? You can look for good nodes from very start! Replace entire loop with:

```
foreach my $a ( keys %$hash )
{
    @{ $hash->{$a}->{ds} } = grep { !/local/i } @{ $hash->{$a}->{ds} };
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Many thanks. This is way more concise and easy to understand. I knew from the beginning there must be an easier way to get this done. This is it. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 5):

`delete` is for elements in hashes. It happens to work on arrays by a quirk of implementation, but it shouldn't be relied on.

For arrays, you want to use splice.

```
splice @{ $ref->{to}->{array} }, $index, 1, ();
```

This replaces the 1-element sublist starting at `$index` with `()`, the empty list.

Comment: I cannot use splice as the index of the element that need be deleted is not constant in my hash. The one I posted in my code is a mock-up of What I am trying to do.

Comment: Sure you can. You use the search as above to -find- the index.

Comment: I have multiple entries with "local" in it. I am not sure about the splice syntax...googling now.

Comment: The "insert" part is optional with splice. So `splice @array, $start, 1` is all you need.

Answer (score 1):

Not much neater but:

```
foreach my $a ( keys %$hash )
{
    my $temp;
    foreach ( @{ $hash->{$a}->{ds} } ) 
    {   
        push(@$temp, $_) unless $_ =~ /local/i;
    }
    $hash->{$a}->{ds} = $temp;
}
```

Delete doesn't alter the array structure, it just alters the array content. Because of this in your method you need to grep for defined entries to create a new array of the structure you desire, then overwrite the old array.

edit:
This is better explained on [perldoc page for delete](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/delete.html)

> delete() may also be used on arrays and array slices, but its behavior is less straightforward. Although exists() will return false for deleted entries, deleting array elements never changes indices of existing values; use shift() or splice() for that. However, if all deleted elements fall at the end of an array, the array's size shrinks to the position of the highest element that still tests true for exists(), or to 0 if none do.

edit:

As pointed out by mob splice will do what you want:

```
foreach my $a ( keys %$hash )
{
    for(0..$#{ $hash->{$a}->{ds} } ) 
    {   
        splice( @{ $hash->{$a}->{ds} }, $_, 1 ) if $hash->{$a}->{ds}->[ $_ ] =~ /local/i;
    }
}
```

Comment: `splice` is a builtin that can remove item 3 from a list and adjust all higher indexes down by one.

Comment: I cannot use splice as the index of the element that need be deleted is not constant in my hash. The one I posted in my code is a mock-up of What I am trying to do.

Comment: +1 for the explanation about `delete` and splice example. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
for my $h (values %$hash){
    $h->{ds} = [ grep { $_ !~ /local/i } @{$h->{ds}} ];
}
```

Comment: This is similar to the the one I have accepted. but this is more cryptic and I think I will not be able to interpret what it is doing a couple of weeks down the line. I am learning perl :). Wish I could accept 2 answers.

Answer (score 0):

You could use List::MoreUtils qw/first_idx/ to get the index of /local/ like so

```
first_idx { $_ =~ /local/i } @{$hash->{$a}->{ds}};
```

Then do what you want with that.